# Android: How do I make a splash screen until webview finishes loading the url?

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

How do I make a splash screen until webview finishes loading the url?

my files

MainActivity.java
SplashActivity.java

splash.xml
activity_main.xml

Code  MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView website;
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Activity activity = this;

        website = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        website.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        website.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
                {   
             @Override
             public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             return false;
             }  
        });
        website.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) 
               {
                activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
                if(progress == 100)
                  activity.setTitle(website.getTitle());
                WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); 
                }
        });


        website.loadUrl("http://*********.com/");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Code SplashActivity.java

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.jehad4t.stikana.R;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    private long splashDelay = 5000; //5 seconds

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
        {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            }

        };

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task, splashDelay);
    }
}
```

Code splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/splash" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Code activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In SplashActivity change :

`private long splashDelay = 5000;` to `private long splashDelay = 0;`

```
       @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
```

In MainActivity XML file : add one linearlayout.
In MainActivity java file : provide your splash image to this linear layout which you have provided in your splash.java file.
Like mLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash);

This works for me.

Comment: i do what you say but .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash); error

Comment: Do u have splash.png file in your drawable folder?

Comment: Clean your project and then give a try.

Comment: i make it apk and i install it on mobile but (( unfortunately, appname has stopped. ))

Comment: Check this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iHotelApp This behaves the same way that you want in your app.

Comment: Ok..let me know if you find any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try using WebViewClient, it has a onPageFinished method. Example from my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.whatever);

    //make your splash visible here

    WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.yourWebView);
    //remove flicker
    browser.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //make it invisible here
        }
    });

    browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/whatever.html");
}
```

Comment: I know this is so old thread. But now I got a similar problem. In your solution, where did you ask the webview to load in background. when I used this kind of code, splash screen is showing up for given delay and then webview is loading sequentially. no background work is done to load the url before the MainActivity is coming up.